# pricing relationship between SPY and IVV

Tags: etf

SPY and IVV are both non-levered ETFs of the S&P 500 Index. However there are some subtle differences between them. SPY pays cash dividends while IVV reinvests their dividends. IVV allows derivatives in its portfolios as well, among other differences. What is a good way to price the SPY - IVV spread?